# FOR LOOP through a NAMED RANGE PASSED as an INPUT

Tags: vba, for-loop

A lot of examples I see SHOW A RNG SPECIFIED AS A STATIC INPUT (EX... A1:A3)

I hope to pass in ANY range and not have to sub specify it internally, i.e. dynamic

```
Function sMad(rng As Range)

    Dim count As Double

    Dim rCell As Range

    Dim medianMatrix() As Double

    'bad estimator for count, only measures 1 column
    'count = rng.count
```

...

```
    For i = 0 To count
```

...

```
    Next i

    sMad = count

End Function
```

**Update**

I failed to include a proper truncated view of my code previously (count isn't based on anything atm, but it was supposed to be based on rng.count)   However, I did figure out how to loop through the rng, but I'm ultimately trying to read each cell's value at each position.

```
Function sMad(rng As Range)
    Rem sMad = LoopRangeApplication.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)

    Dim count As Double

    For Each cell In rng

        count = count + 1

    Next cell

    sMad = count

End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, for example you can just pass ANY range into the function you have there, provided it is a valid 'range'

Comment: thanks for the comment, I don't think I typed my question corretly.  I was able to figure it out

Comment: okay, I updated it.  I'm trying to access each cell's value at said point.

Comment: Two things: 1) You were looking to 'read each cell's value', yet your function is counting # of cells included in the range. Are you trying to achieve both at the same time?  2) It is still undefined what is it meant by 'dynamic', right now the function does take ANY range you pass, even the range change during runtime